# Jenkins cannot find JAVA_HOME automatically

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have java 1.8 installed and environment variable set on my windows 10 laptop. But when I run my maven project through Jenkins pipeline, Jenkins cannot find JAVA_HOME variable by itself.
Would anyone guide me so resolve this issue, please?

[image]

Comment: did you add JAVA_HOME into your environmental virable?

Comment: Yes I have. You can see in the image I have attached that JAVA_HOME environment variable is set and path is given too. Still Jenkins unable to recognize it.

Comment: Could you please share the exact exception that your getting?

Comment: @user7650733 make sure the `Path` has jdk-location/bin added to its variables.

Comment: Did you try to define JAVA_HOME in the System variables? I can only see it in the user variables

Comment: [Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Clean)
[Pipeline] echo
cleaning framework..!!
[Pipeline] bat
[TestNG] Running batch script

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TestNG>mvn clean 

Error: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment. 
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the 
location of your Java installation. 

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: @user7650733 Also make sure Jenkins default config file is configured with these variables. Probably in `/etc/default/jenkins`

Comment: Yes Andrew,  I have given --> %JAVA_HOME%\bin  in the system variable.

Comment: @nullpointer
Manage Jenkins-->Global Tool Configuration-->JDK -->
name: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91
I am using Jenkins 2.32.3.

Comment: You should set `JAVA_HOME` in the system variables, not only `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` in the `PATH` system variable. Your user variable cannot be used by Jenkins as Jenkins is probably running with a different user.

Comment: In my opinion, you shouldn't use the system Java for your builds. It makes switching Java versions much more difficult, and forces slave nodes to have Java pre-installed as well. Your best bet is to use the Global Tool JDK Installation, and then use the `withEnv` custom path variables `"PATH+JDK=${tool name: 'jdk-1.8.0_25', type: 'hudson.model.JDK'}/bin"`

Comment: Yes brov. You are right. But when I select JDK Installation, Jenkins is asking me for oracle account which I dont have and kind of not ready to create one yet. However, your suggestion is quite thoughtful and important. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global properties
Check the box 'Environment variables' and add the JAVA_HOME path